# How to implement atomic_min?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, atomic, compare-and-swap

I need to implement an `atomic_min` function, that is equivalent to:

```
static void atomic_min(u64 *ptr, u64 value)                                        
{
    enter critical section
    *ptr = min(*ptr, value);
    exit critical section                                                                               
}
```

This could be implement it using `cmpxchg`:

```
static void atomic_min(u64 *ptr, u64 value)                                        
{                                                                                
    u64 old, new;                                                            
    do {                                                                     
        old = *ptr;                                                        
        new = min(old, value);                                           
    } while (cmpxchg(ptr, old, new) != old);
}
```

which looks pretty inefficient to me. Is there a better way to implement `atomic_min`?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted, or why they think it is opinion-based, but I think this is a good question. I, too see no alternative to `cmpxchg`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I was referring to good performance. The loop around `cmpxchg` feels to me that it defies the whole purpose of atomic operations and that the code behaves as if a spinlock was used.

Answer (score 3):

*Atomic arithmetic instructions*, provided by architectures, are mostly limited with addition/substruction and bitwise operations. (At least, Linux kernel provides only those operations for arch-independent code).

Because `min` cannot be expressed via *single* addition, substruction or bitwise operations, for implement "atomic_min" there is no other choice than using of `cmpxchg`.

Comment: You can express min with addition/subtraction and bitwise operations. Take a look here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

Comment: @Radon: Thanks for the point, you are right. Actually, such expressions are irrelevant for "atomic" case: it should be *single-instruction* expression for being atomic. I have fixed the answer, so it shouldn't be any misinterpretation.